# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment with navigation drawer and getting Error YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

I wanted to impement YouTubePlayerSupportFragment with navigation drawer but i m getting error 
**YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@213d7588. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 70, right: 0, bottom: 714..**

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    mYoutubePlayerFragment.initialize(
            "Youtube Key",
            new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                    if (!wasRestored) {
                        player.loadVideo(newPost.get("url").toString());
                        player.play();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                        YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
                    if (result.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                        result.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), 1).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity(),
                                "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationFailure(): "
                                        + result.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment,
            mYoutubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from ducumentation youtube player shoudbe topest element and have minimal size of 200*110 dp. If it is smaller - player will stop. If any view (even invisible) will overlap the youtube player - player will stop